# SQL Server and windows authentication in IIS7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7, windows-authentication

I'm trying to get an ASP.NET website running on Vista (IIS7), using SQL Server and Windows Authentication. No matter what I do, when I connect to the database, I get the exception:

```
    SqlException was unhandled
    Login failed for user 'MyDomain\MachineName$'.
```

It doesn't seem to matter what settings I apply, I cannot get IIS7 to pass through my Windows login credentials.

Extra details:

- Both the SQL Server and my local machine are on ActiveDirectory
- Vista Enterprise, IIS7
- SQL Server 2005
- Anonymous Authentication disabled, Windows Authentication enabled
- Impersonation on/off makes no difference
- All Identities (NetworkService, LocalSystem, etc) give the same result
- Classic and integrated pipelines give the same result

Help!

Comment: Is ISS and SQL Server on different servers or the same server?

Comment: Yep, they're running on different servers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Impersonation on/off makes all the difference, when properly configured. What you want is caled 'constrained delegation' and you need to configure IIS and ASP for it:

- [How To: Use Protocol Transition and Constrained Delegation in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998355.aspx)
- [Configure ASP.NET Impersonation Authentication (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730708%28WS.10%29.aspx)
- [Configuring Servers for Delegation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296638%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: This sounds like the ticket, thanks Remus. I'll try this when I get back to work tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

By default, the IIS server is not allowed to `impersonate` you towards the SQL Server.  There's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx) on how to configure it.  The configuration process is complex and error prone.

If your production ISS and SQL Server run on different servers, you'll need a domain admin to configure impersonation trust between the two servers.  This is typically a no-go in a big organization.

In addition to not being deployed by normal admins, impersonation also prevents users from sharing their connections in the SQL connection pool.  This results in a very noticeable performance penalty for even small (5+ users) websites.

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip. To be honest I just want to get it working on my local machine; once it gets deployed I'll leave it to the network admins to work it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create a new user account for your application, grant it the appropriate rights on the Sql Server, and then set the application pool to run under this new account?
This is what I usually do, and it works. I'm not running my application under NetworkService, LocalSystem or other builtin accounts.

Comment: Well no; but I need to use the integrated Windows Authentication in order to work out who the user of the application is. Usually I would do the same thing, otherwise! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does your connection string contain `Integrated Security=SSPI`?

Have you switched the asp.net context to be a domain user as well?

Here is an MSDN article on this topic

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xzyzb0f.aspx

Comment: Integrated security will cmause IIS to authenticate as itself, typically `IUSR_ComputerName`